# Doctrine:Fatal error: Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am writing a PHPUnit test, where I am calling the following method:

```
 public function searchBy(array $filters = array())
{
    $qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('c') ;

    if ( ! empty($filters['fooTranslations']))
    {
        $qb->leftJoin('c.translations', 'tr');


        $qb->groupBy('c.id');
        $qb->orderBy('c.id');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

    return null;

}
```

which returns exactly what I want.

But, when I am calling it as part of my unit test, I am getting the following fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on a non-object
```

This is my simple PHPUnit test:

```
class FooManagerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
protected $fooManager;

public  function  setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->fooManager = new FooManager();
}


public function testReturnsArray()
{
    $filters = [
        'fooTranslations' => true
    ];

    $response = $this->fooManager->searchBy($filters);

    $this->assertEquals(array(), $response);
}
}
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: the `getRepository` method isn't returning an object.  Look at what that is returning.  You might need to do more in the setup for your test.

Comment: But then, how it does work inside searchBy()?
When I run it from my application

Comment: It does work inside searchBy, because it is initialized differently. It loads the whole Symfony bloat of Kernel etc. For example if you want to access a Repository inside a test, you first have to boot the Kernel, then load the EntityManager, then you have access to the repository. Also you searchBy function should be in a Repository.

Comment: That is probably the reason. Thanks alot for the help.